# Calling WCF service from jQuery Ajax using POST method

Tags: wcf, jquery

I have a following WCF method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UserService/AddUser", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public User AddUser(string LoginId, string Name)
{
    var user = input;

    // Some business logic here

    return user;
}
```

And I have a jQuery Ajax client code as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var input =
            {
                LoginId: $("#LoginId").val(),
                Name: $("#Name").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "http://localhost:2000/UserService/AddUser",
                data: JSON.stringify(input),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (userViewModel) {
                    var user = userViewModel;
                    alert(user);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Once ajax invoke AddUser method LoginId and Name value is set in AddUser method's two parameter, however, What I want to do is having a method signature as below

```
public User AddUser(User user)
```

Of course, User class have LoginId and Name properties in it.

How to bind client's parameter to user instance automatically without setting the value manually?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution by myself

I should wrap the json data with object name as follow :

```
        var input =
        {
            "user": 
            {
                "LoginId": $("#LoginId").val(),
                "Name": $("#Name").val()
            }
        };
```